# Database design for dentist app

Tags: database, medical

So I'm doing a web app for my sister, as she recently received her degree on odontology.

I'm having a bit of a struggle with the database design though...

I'm obviously supposed to have an appointment table (tbl_appointment), appointments may have treatments associated to them, and those treatments all have different attributes (columns).

So I'm thinking I should have a tbl_appointment and also a tbl_treatment, I'm not sure on how to link those tables as to have multiple treatment types, with different treatment parameters and save the treatment data related to the appointment.

What do you think would be a good approach to this? I already have something drawn out but it definitely doesn't seem good as I end up having one table for each treatment type and I don't think thats the best solution.

**EDIT**

As this wasn't clear enough, here's a screenshot of how my actual db looks like.

If I implement the treatments as I did the periodontogram, I'm gonna end up with 20 tables one for each treatment type. I want to avoid that!

[image]

**EDIT**

@Ian Kenney, so if I got what you were suggesting right, this is how the portion of the database we're discussing should look like...

[image]

Am I right? Don't pay attention to the relation types as they're all 1:1, I am aware I should use some M:N in there, but it was just for the example.

Comment: there should be a primary key to identify the appointments, such as `appointmend_id` or some such.. you would then use that as a foreign key in the `tbl_treatment` table.  You have a column `appointment_id` that stores the appointment that the treatment is linked to.

Comment: I would also recommend a table for doctors/orthodonsist or whatever the cust would be meeting with and a `doctor_id`. use that as a foreign key in `tbl_treatment`. if you want to add customers with a `tbl_customer` and a `cust_id` and fk that as well that probably wouldnt be bad. Then you start thinking about families where you're going to be treating the kid, but the parent wouldbe the contact, and are you going to store insurance information, if so it needs to be encrypted.....Soon you cant help but wonder how anyone ever finished a software that does this

Comment: Oh I think I haven't made myself clear... I do know how to relate tables, its just that I can't think of the structure of the database as to meet these requirements I listed. I mean should I have a table for treatments and another for treatment_data? and maybe another one for treatment_types? where should I specify which parameters a treatment take? It's actually pretty hard to make myself clear about this

Comment: That depends on what level of normalization you are going for.  See http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html for more information regarding database normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach for the various treatment types would be to look at the attributes that are common between them, for example it may include:

- name
- description
- price
- time_required

These become the columns of tbl_treatment

Then use an additional table for other (treatment specific) attributes tbl_treatment_attributes with a structure like:

- treatment_id
- attribute_name
- attribute_value

Each treatment could have many additional attributes, the acceptable attributes (including defaults) could be managed in tbl_treatment_defaults

- treatment_id
- attribute_name
- field_type
- validations
- default_value

**EDIT**

```
+-------------------+              +--------------------+
| tbl_treatment     |              | tbl_treatment_type |
+===================+              +====================+
|*treatment_id      |              |*treatment_type_id  |
|+treatment_type_id |<-------------| treatment_name     |
|  ......           |              | ......             |
+-------------------+              +--------------------+
         |                                   |
         v                                   v
+--------------------------+       +------------------------+
| tbl_treatment_attributes |       | tbl_treatment_defaults |
+==========================+       +========================+
|*treatment_id             |       |*treatment_type_id      |
| attribute_name           |<------| attribute_name         |
| attribute_value          |       | default_value          |
| ........                 |       | .......                |
+--------------------------+       +------------------------+
```

Comment: How should I go about specifying always the same attributes for each kind of treatment? Should I do that client-side ?

Comment: edited answer - you can use an additional table to define the permitted attributes for each treatment type

Comment: Please see the second edit to check if I got it right

Comment: This is over-abstracted.

Answer (score 0):

The `tbl_appointment` appointment table should only have appointment data and `patientId` (foreign key into your `tbl_Patient` table)

You should have a 3rd table called `tbl_Visit` that contains a foreign key into the `tbl_appointment`. Then another table called `tbl_Visit_treatment` that has `VisitId` and `TreatmentId`. So this `tbl_Visit_treatment` is the many-to-many relationship table that tracks all the treatments done in each visit.

As for TreatmentType(s), that will simply be a type table called `tbl_TreatmentType` with `ID`, `Name`, `Code` and `Description` fields. The `TreatmentId` will be a foreign key in the `tbl_Treatment`table.

Comment: and what about the specific treatment data? I mean data that should be a field in one treatment type but not the other

Comment: That will be in the `tbl_Treatment` as a field called `Description`. If you want to track the exact way the treatment was rendered per patient's visit, then it should be a field in the `tbl_Visit_Treatment` in a field called `TreatmentDescription`. So for example, if you have `"Root Canal"` as a treatment, `tbl_Treatment` will have `ID` = 2, `Code` = "ROOTC", `Description`  = "Root Canal Treatment", `InsuranceCode` = "XYZ01" etc. And the `tbl_Visit_Treatment` will have something like `VisitID` = 4, `TreatmentId` =2 `TreatmentDescription` = "Remove root in root canal Teeth S2, capped." etc.

Comment: But what about the attributes to be saved on that root canal treatment? For example, how would you save the tooth number as an attribute instead of a string in the description?